# Syntactic sugar string concatenation when updating variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

In most programming languages I have used you can do something like (where s is a string).

```
s = "Hello"
s += " World"
```

I try to do something similar in VBA and it does not work. I have tried

```
s = "Hello"
s += " World" 
s &= " World"
```

In the end I have done

```
s = "Hello"
s =  s & " World"
```

Can I do this without the s &

Comment: You have found the One True Way (as far as Access is concerned...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Access doesn't use VB.NET and the `&=` concatenation operator is VB.NET specific.

Even in Access 2010 VBA is still VB6.5 (old school P-Code|Native/COM VB) and hasn't been upgraded to use VB.NET.

Answer (score 4):

VBA has two [concatenation operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w00s0c3k.aspx) - the `&` and the `+`.

However, it doesn't have the shortcut of `=+` or `=&` - you have to write the full syntax:

```
s = s & " World"
```

Or

```
s = s + " World"
```

Though `+` comes with a warning (since it is also used as the addition operator):

> Although you can also use the + operator to concatenate two character strings, you should use the & operator for concatenation to eliminate ambiguity and provide self-documenting code.

Comment: +1 Thank you for mentioning the caveat to using the `+` operator in string concatenation. Too many people give advice to VB programmers and forget this important detail. The *reason* for this is that VB allows extremely loose typing through the `Variant` type, and it's very easy to be surprised at the result when you add two `Variants` together.

Comment: Not to mention when a null is included in the mix.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's not better than just using the ampersand

```
s = "Hello"
s = Join(Array(s, "World"))
```